# warning Using the font Tahoma in versions of Xcode prior to 4.2 may have unexpected results.ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6

I am getting this warning in `Xcode`...plz give me idea to solve this warning issue

> Using the font Tahoma in versions of Xcode prior to 4.2 may have unexpected results.iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IB,Go to **File inspector** inwhich under **interface builder document** in document versioning make **development** value as greater than current value(xcode version).

Answer (score 0):

May Be Mistake Should be in How To add Font in Application.

This is Step for, How to add custom font in Application.

1 - Add `.TTF` font in your application
2 - Modify the `application-info.plist file`.
3 - Add the key **"Fonts provided by application"** to a new row
4 - and add each `.TTF` file (of font) to each line.

For more info read [This](http://www.developers-life.com/how-to-include-ttf-fonts-to-ios-app.html) and [This](http://www.waterworld.com.hk/en/node/157) site.

> FOR Your INFORMATION :

**For Bold**

```
// Equivalent to [UIFont fontWithName:@"FontName-BoldMT" size:17]
UIFont* font = [UIFont fontWithFamilyName:@"FontName" traits:GSBoldFontMask size:17];
```

**And bold/italic**

```
UIFont* font = [UIFont fontWithMarkupDescription:@"font-family: FontName; font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold/italic;"]; // set here, either bold/italic.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to xib
2. click on the "show file Inspector icon" (first icon).
3. Under the document versioning change your development greater than 4.2